# Redirect to Stripe Checkout from Sveltekit endpoint not working

Tags: stripe-payments, svelte, sveltekit

I have a +server.js endpoint set up in my Sveltekit app that successfully creates a session with a url when I hit it:

```
const stripe = new Stripe(SECRET_STRIPE_KEY)

    try {
        console.log("Attempting to create Stripe session...")
        
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            mode: "payment",
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: lineItems,
            success_url: `http://localhost:5173/checkout/success`,
            cancel_url: 'http://localhost:5173/checkout/details'
        });

        console.log(session)
        response.redirect(307, session.url)

        const newOrder = await createOrder(order, items)

        return new Response({
            status: 200,
            headers: {},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                sessionId: session.id,
                order: newOrder
            })    
        });
    } catch (err) {
        return new Response({ 
            status:500,
            headers:{},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                error: err
            })
        });
    }
```

However, what it doesn't do is redirect to the Stripe Checkout page and I don't know why. I've tried `throw redirect(307, session.url)`, `response.redirect(307, session.url)` and `goto(session.url)` but none work, and there are no errors anywhere to explain it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Couple quick questions up front: Have you confirmed that that line of code is actually being executed? If so, can you see the network response in the developer console on your client? Can you redirect to other URLs if you hard code one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this. I was taking the wrong approach. I instead needed to simply pass the id of the created Stripe session back to the front end where Stripe's JS library has a redirect method that takes the id as an argument.